# Java RMI Server problems

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I apologize in advance for what's likely to be an obvious problem, but I've been trying to get this working all day and I can't figure out how to get this to work. In short: my RMIregistry can't find the interface class of my RMI server app.

I'm running rmiregistry.exe through Eclipse with these arguments:

```
1234 -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false
```

And I got the following RMI server:

```
        package es.test.innova.pruebas.test;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.rmi.Naming;
    import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

    public class TestImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Test
    {
        public TestImpl() throws RemoteException {}

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            try
            {           
             if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
                 System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
                 } 

                TestImpl obj = new TestImpl();

                Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1234/Test",obj);
                System.out.println("Connected to registry!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("HelloImpl err: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String validate(File f) throws RemoteException {
            return "hello world";
        }
}
```

Which I then run with these arguments:

```
-Djava.security.policy=C:\D\RMI\policy.all -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/D/Proyectos/Firma/validarfirma/
```

The policy file referenced is this:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission "", "";
};
```

The codebase parameter references the project's folder, through I've also tried directing it at the folder's bin folder and even directly at the .class files, as mentioned in other answers in this site.

Regardless of what I try, I keep getting this error:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: es.test.innova.pruebas.test.Test
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:378)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at es.test.innova.pruebas.test.TestImpl.main(TestImpl.java:25)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: es.test.innova.pruebas.test.Test
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: es.test.innova.pruebas.test.Test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:1206)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClassForName(LoaderHandler.java:1219)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(LoaderHandler.java:729)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:673)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:610)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1556)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1512)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    ... 13 more
HelloImpl err: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: es.test.innova.pruebas.test.Test
```

Class not found. I've tried running everything manually instead of using Eclipse, running rmi directly from the .class file folder, compiling the Server as a .jar and using that instead... And of course I've fiddled with the codebase parameter a bunch. I've tried everything I could think of, but I'm stuck.

The thing is I must be setting the codebase wrong or someting like that, but I don't see how. The registry just can't find my classes.

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out here. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you have an interface called Test in the same package as TestImpl ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/D/Proyectos/Firma/validarfirma/
```

The meaning of this is that the missing class should be located as:

```
C:/D/Proyectos/Firma/validarfirma/es/test/innova/pruebas/test/Test.class
```